# Not getting value from nested hash table

Tags: powershell, hash

I am not getting "starttime" value below, any idea what I am missing ? The below snippet is part of big script. When I run "$_" I do get correct key value pair but not able to get value based on key name. What is the best method to iterate through hash table ?

```
$clusterstats = @{
    server1 = @{
                         'NPC Netapp napsdccp138v_prod'= @{
                                                              'nolongerneeded' =  ''
                                                              'status' =  'kRunning'
                                                              'starttime' =  '01/14/2023 08=00PM'
                                                              'clients' =  {

                                                                          }
                                                          }
                         'napsdccp500v_CIFS_new_prod'= @{
                                                            nolongerneeded =  ''
                                                            status =  'kRunning'
                                                            starttime =  '01/13/2023 07=00PM'
                                                            clients =  {

                                                                        }
                                                        }
                         'NPC Netapp napsdccp137v_prod'= @{
                                                              nolongerneeded =  ''
                                                              'status'=  'null'
                                                              'starttime'=  '01/11/2023 09=00PM'
                                                              'clients'=  @{
                                                                              'wfs_prod_home'=  99
                                                                          }
                                                          }
                         'NPC Netapp napsdccp500v_prod'= @{
                                                              'nolongerneeded'=  ''
                                                              'status'=  'kRunning'
                                                              'starttime'=  '01/13/2023 10=00PM'
                                                              'clients'=  {

                                                                          }
                                                          }
                         'NPC Netapp napsdccp352v_prod'=  @{
                                                              'nolongerneeded'=  ''
                                                              'status'=  'kRunning'
                                                              'starttime'=  '01/14/2023 07=00PM'
                                                              'clients'=  {

                                                                          }
                                                          }
                     }


    server2 = @{
                        'NPC Netapp napsdccp353v_prod'=  @{
                                                              'nolongerneeded'=  ''
                                                              'status'=  'kRunning'
                                                              'starttime'=  '01/15/2023 07=00PM'
                                                              'clients'=  {

                                                                          }
                                                          }
                }
    server3 = @{


               }
}

                $clusterstats.GetEnumerator()|sort-object -Property {$_.key} |foreach {  
                                    $server = $_.key
                                    $jobs = @() 
                                foreach ($job in $_.value.keys){
                                                $jobs += $job
                
                                                        }                                                      
                                if ($jobs.count -gt 0){
                                foreach ($job in $jobs){
     
                                $clusterstats.$($server).$($job).GetEnumerator()|ForEach-Object {
                                           $starttime = $_.value.starttime
                                           $starttime 
                                                                                               }

                                                       }
                                                         }
                                                         }
```

why $starttime is not showing ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be a bit complicated structure you have but this should help you get started:

```
foreach($server in $clusterstats.GetEnumerator()) {
    foreach($service in $server.Value.GetEnumerator()) {
        if($service.Value.ContainsKey('starttime')) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Server    = $server.Key
                Service   = $service.Key
                StartTime = $service.Value['starttime']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using the example data the output would be:

```
Server  Service                      StartTime
------  -------                      ---------
server1 napsdccp500v_CIFS_new_prod   01/13/2023 07=00PM
server1 NPC Netapp napsdccp352v_prod 01/14/2023 07=00PM
server1 NPC Netapp napsdccp137v_prod 01/11/2023 09=00PM
server1 NPC Netapp napsdccp500v_prod 01/13/2023 10=00PM
server1 NPC Netapp napsdccp138v_prod 01/14/2023 08=00PM
server2 NPC Netapp napsdccp353v_prod 01/15/2023 07=00PM
```

Unless you have a real need to use a hashtable of hashtables, I don't think this is leveraging the good qualities of `IDictionary` since you need to enumerate all key value pairs and in that sense this task might be simplified by simply using `PSCustomObject`.

Comment: Above helped me good. Santiago . Thank you . what would loop for getting individual value from clients @{} tables ?

Comment: @raju glad it helped, if you need to loop on `clients` that would require one more loop under `$service`, it should be something like `foreach($client in $service.Value['clients'].GetEnumerator()) { ..` something like that I think. You can ask a new question if that doesnt help

Comment: it did not work. getting message "does not contain a method named 'GetEnumerator'.foreach($client in $service.Value['clients'].GetEnumerator()) {
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound